# seaborn style whitegrid with no ticks

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, python-3.8, xticks

I want to create a scatter plot without x or y ticks. But I would like to see the plot in whitegrid style.  When I explicitly sets the xticks, I lose the whitegrids too. Any tricks ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots(frameon=False)

colormap = np.array(["orange","cyan"])
x = np.array([2,2,2,4,4,4,4]*10)
y = np.array([2,4])
col = np.array(['b','g'])
colors = colormap[np.where(y==x[:,None])[1]]
Y = np.random.random((70,2))
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
ax.scatter(Y[:,0], Y[:,1], c=colors)
```

Comment: Plot the ticks in the background color?

Comment: @Mr.T how can i do it ?  is it possible with seaborn ?

Comment: The recommended way to hide the tick labels is `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())` for both x and y axis. If you also want to hide the tick marks: `ax.tick_params(axis="both", length=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the example you can refer as suggested by Mr T, you can make `xticks` font color to background color.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(frameon=False)
colormap = np.array(["orange","cyan"])

x = np.array([2,2,2,4,4,4,4]*10)
y = np.array([2,4])

col = np.array(['b','g'])
colors = colormap[np.where(y==x[:,None])[1]]

Y = np.random.random((70,2))

ax.scatter(Y[:,0], Y[:,1], c=colors)
ax.tick_params(axis="both", colors="white") #suggested by Mr T, easier way
# plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(),color="white", backgroundcolor="white") # suggested by Me
# plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(),color="white", backgroundcolor="white") # suggested by Me
```

I have adopted Mr T's answer which is easier and less complicated.

[image: OutputImage]

Comment: @Mr T : I have used your suggestion, your is more easier than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You want to remove the tick *labels*, not the ticks themselves. Best to toggle their visibility attribute:

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
```